# Lista Linear Simplesmente Encadeada

Tags: c, lista

Minha dúvida era como fazer o programa sem alocação dinâmica, estou aprendendo LLSE agora, e todos que acho são com alocação dinâmica, mas meu professor disse que só usaria alocação dinâmica na segunda metade da disciplina, se puderem ajudar com links ou explicando, seria de muita ajuda, segue abaixo um exemplo da estrutura que ele passou pra usar no programa, que no geral se diferencia das estruturas que vejo em outros exemplos:

```
typedef struct {
char info;
int prox;
} no;

typedef struct {
no vet[MAX];
} LLSE;
```

Comment: Olha, ao meu ver, nesse caso, tu teria que saber quantos structs exatamente iriam ser usadas durante a execução do programa e definir isso previamente com um vetor. Desse jeito ai, desconheço se é possível fazer sem alocação dinâmica. Não acho que faça muito sentido usar desse jeito sem ser com alocação dinâmica. Vamos ver se alguém com mais experiência sabe responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde Weslley,

Você pode implementar uma lista através de um *array* estático de N elementos, onde N é o número máximo de itens que sua lista suporta.

**Simplificando sua estrutura**:

```
typedef struct {

char info[MAX_TAM]; //Vetor para guardar a informação
int primeiro, ultimo; //Primeiro e último elemento do vetor

} LLSE;
```

O que eu fiz acima foi basicamente unir as duas *structs* e tirar o ponteiro **prox**, pois já que vamos implementar nossa lista através de um vetor, que já é administrado por um ponteiro não precisamos, dessa variável.

Agora que já montamos o *struct* é só declarar dentro do main e criar as funções para administrar essa lista. Não existe um conjunto de funções que serve para todo tipo de lista, mas existem algumas básicas que você vai precisar.

**São elas:**

```
void inicializaLista(LLSE *lista); //Opicional, mas recomendo.
int insereElemento(char elemento, LLSE *lista);
int removeElemento(char elemento, LLSE *lista);
```

**Aplicação:**

```
void inicializaLista(LLSE *lista){
lista->primeiro = lista->ultimo = -1;
}
```

A função inicializa irá dar um parâmetro para testar se a lista está vazia/foi inicializada, pois já que se trata de um vetor que começa da posição 0 o teste `if(lista->ultimo == 0)` pode não ser tão eficaz, mas claro que tudo depende de como você está implementando sua lista, como eu disse: é apenas uma recomendação pessoal.

```
int insereElemento(char elemento, LLSE lista){

if( lista->ultimo >= MAX_TAM-1){
  return(0); //Lista cheia
 }else if(lista->ultimo == -1)){
  lista->primeiro=0; //Caso esteja vazia, o primeiro elemento recebe 0
 }
 lista->ultimo++;
 lista->info[lista->ultimo]= elemento;
 return(1);
```

Antes de inserir temos que, primeiro, testar se a lista está cheia ou vazia, em seguida incrementamos 1 ao valor do último elemento, inserimos o elemento e encerramos a função, se forma que "primeiro" e "último" serão nossas referencias de posição no vetor, usando para testar se ela já está cheia ou vazia.

Tente implementar o `int removeElemento();` por questões de treino.

Abraço e bons estudos!

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou fazer aqui a parte de remoção

Comment: Disponha, fico feliz em ajudar!